# how to track pipeline script log from class file

Tags: logging, jenkins, groovy, classloader, jenkins-pipeline

I'm loading groovy classes in pipeline script,how can I check the log of that class methods while execution. I'm not able to see the println (or SoP) statements of the methods in jenkins console. Due to this I'm not able to debug the methods being called in the pipeline script. The same is running fine in my IntelliJIDE. Any input appreciated. Below is my code

```
node {
   def ConfigEntityObj
   def ServiceEntityObj   
   def DBConnClassObj
   def TibcoServiceXMLClassObj


   stage 'TibcoConfig'
   echo 'Reading Tibco configuration!'
   println "****************INSIDE PIPELINE****************"
    def parent = getClass().getClassLoader()
    def loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent)

    ConfigEntityObj = loader.parseClass(new File("//opt//tibco//deploy_tool//Tibco_Automation//src/com//merck//Entity//ConfigEntity.java")).newInstance()
    ServiceEntityObj = loader.parseClass(new File("//opt//tibco//deploy_tool//Tibco_Automation//src/com//merck//Entity//ServiceEntity.java")).newInstance()    

    DBConnClassObj = loader.parseClass(new File("//opt//tibco//deploy_tool//Tibco_Automation//src//com//merck//comet//DBConnectionManager.groovy")).newInstance()
    TibcoServiceXMLClassObj = loader.parseClass(new File("//opt//tibco//deploy_tool//Tibco_Automation//src//com//merck//comet//TibcoServiceXML.groovy")).newInstance()




    TibcoServiceXMLClassObj.createServiceXML()

    println "Inside the pipeline:" 

    println 'Application Name read task completd!'
     }
```

Comment: the method createServiceXML creates an xml file in the system, I'm able to execute successfully from my IDE, but when I run the same from Pipeline groovy sand box, the xml is not created.

Answer (score 0):

After all the research I understood that the pipeline console doesn't show the logs of your classes, all you have to do is implement log4j in your classes and write the logs to a file on the system. This just fit my requirement.